# How to Iterate over Multiple Worksheets to apply Formatting or Change Sheet Name in python using Openpyxl or xlswriter

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

So I have already created a workbook & post this I want to iterate over all the sheets & apply some formatting. There are a total of 6 sheets and I want to do Freezing of Panes/Changing Sheet Tab Color / Add Grand Totals

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('demand_report_workbook.xlsx')
for sheet in wb:
```

But this fails to work for me. Am I missing a basic point or doing noob error ?!

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the names with wb.sheetnames and after do a loop with the names list:

```
get_sheet=wb.sheetnames

for sheet in get_sheet:
    ws=wb[sheet]
    ...
```